# Can I rotate divergence away? / Can get divergence from a rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, field-theory, partial-derivative

Let $v(x,y)$ be a two-dimensional vector field and let $R(x,y, \theta)$ be the two-dimensional rotation matrix which rotations a vector field around $(x,y)$ an angle $\theta$.

The following two questions are probably very much related:

**Question 1** : Does a $v$ exists such that $\nabla \cdot v = 0$, but $\nabla \cdot (R v) \neq 0$ for some $x,y,\theta$?

**Question 2** : Does a $v$ exists such that $\nabla \cdot v \neq 0$, but $\nabla \cdot (R v) = 0$ for some $x,y,\theta$?

Thank you for any insight in advance.

My intuition tells me that the answer is probably simply "No" to both questions, but I can't prove it.

Comment: If $v = (x,y)$, rotating it by $\pi/2$ gets you a pure rotational field which has zero divergence, and vice versa.

Comment: You have to define what you mean by rotating a vector field. I can imagine several possibilities: (i) Take the vector at location $\vec x$ and rotate it by $R$. (ii) Take the vector at $\vec x$ and put it at location $R\vec x$ without rotating it. (iii) Take the vector at $\vec x$, rotate it by $R$, and put it at location $R\vec x$. The first is what Shuhao assumes. The third is what corresponds to picking up the paper that the vector field is drawn on and rotating the whole thing.

Comment: ... where (iii) does not change the divergence being (non)-zero, while (ii) does (since (i)+(ii)=(iii)).  By the way, the tag field-theory is for different kinds of fields, those in algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Illustrating the example by Shuhao Cao: 
$$v(x,y) = (x,y) ;\qquad u(x,y) = (-y,x)$$
Here $\operatorname{div} v\equiv 2$ and $\operatorname{div} u\equiv 0$. The two fields are related by rotation by $90$ degrees: red has divergence, blue doesn't.

[image: fields]